# best practices with Java try with resources

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Is there any difference between the two below code snippets, in terms of GC, resource closing etc?

or both are same/correct technically?

```
#Option 1
try(Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(path)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

}

#Option 2
try(FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(new File(path);
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

}
```

Just to understand what's the best approach to use in a highly used java application.

Comment: No difference, tried resources get closed and cleaned up. I'd go for option 2 for better readability.

Comment: @Robert it is not correct. In the first example, if the outer constructor (`new OutputStreamWriter(...)`) failed, then internal object (`FileOutputStream`) remains unclosed and leaks resources

Comment: @AterLux Although true in theory, it is extremely unlikely that `OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream, Charset)` throws an exception (basically the only option is to pass in a null for either parameter).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel in this specific usage it is indeed unlikely that OutputStreamWriter will throw, but in a more general case, `try(Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(path)), "bad charset name"))` _will_ leave the FileOutputStream open.

Comment: @k314159 True, but unless you use user input for the character set, or run on a JVM with a limited number of character sets, that is a minor problem compared to the fact that you programmed in a non-existent character set. The stream will get closed eventually by its cleaner (or finalizer in older versions).